# Problems turning off the wireless card

Tags: wireless, ifconfig

I am trying to turn off wireless using the ifconfig command `ifconfig wlan0 down`
and nothing happens no errors displayed in the terminal and wireless networks are still displayed in the network manager.

I can't shut down the system right now cause i'm working in other things.
any solution to turn off the wireless ? thanks

Comment: Why not just turn it off in network manager?

Comment: I can't cause it's grayed out

Comment: You click a wrong place. A little below is a check sign against "Enable Wi-Fi". Just click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn wireless off in Network Manager command-line

```
nmcli nm wifi off
```